# Postgresql recursive CTE results ordering

Tags: postgresql, recursion, common-table-expression

I'm working on a query to pull data out of a hierarchy

e.g.

```
CREATE table org (
   id   INT PRIMARY KEY,
   name TEXT NOT NULL,
   parent_id INT);

INSERT INTO org (id, name) VALUES (0, 'top');
INSERT INTO org (id, name, parent_id) VALUES (1, 'middle1', 0);
INSERT INTO org (id, name, parent_id) VALUES (2, 'middle2', 0);
INSERT INTO org (id, name, parent_id) VALUES (3, 'bottom3', 1);

WITH RECURSIVE parent_org (id, parent_id, name) AS (
  SELECT id, parent_id, name
  FROM org
  WHERE id = 3
UNION ALL
    SELECT o.id, o.parent_id, o.name
    FROM   org o, parent_org po
    WHERE  po.parent_id = o.id)
SELECT id, parent_id, name
FROM parent_org;
```

It works as expected.

```
3 1 "bottom3"
1 0 "middle1"
0   "top"
```

It's also returning the data in the order that I expect, and it makes sense to me that it would do this because of the way that the results would be discovered.

The question is, can I count on the order being like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a defined order. In the [*Postgres* `WITH` doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html), they give the following example:

```
WITH RECURSIVE search_graph(id, link, data, depth, path, cycle) AS (
        SELECT g.id, g.link, g.data, 1,
          ARRAY[ROW(g.f1, g.f2)],
          false
        FROM graph g
      UNION ALL
        SELECT g.id, g.link, g.data, sg.depth + 1,
          path || ROW(g.f1, g.f2),
          ROW(g.f1, g.f2) = ANY(path)
        FROM graph g, search_graph sg
        WHERE g.id = sg.link AND NOT cycle
)
SELECT * FROM search_graph;
```

About which they say in a **Tip** box (formatting mine):

> The recursive query evaluation algorithm produces its output in
>   **breadth-first** search order. You can display the results in **depth-first**
>   search order by making the outer query `ORDER BY` a "path" column
>   constructed in this way.

You do appear to be getting *breadth-first* output in your case above based on the `INSERT` statements, so I would say you could, if you wanted, modify your outer `SELECT` to order it in another fashion.

I believe the analog for *depth-first* in your case would probably be this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE parent_org (id, parent_id, name) AS (
  SELECT id, parent_id, name
  FROM org
  WHERE id = 3
UNION ALL
    SELECT o.id, o.parent_id, o.name
    FROM   org o, parent_org po
    WHERE  po.parent_id = o.id)
SELECT id, parent_id, name
FROM parent_org
ORDER BY id;
```

As I would expect (running things through in my head) that to yield this:

```
0   "top"
1 0 "middle1"
3 1 "bottom3"
```